# Serializing Entity Framework Entity State with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization, asp.net-web-api

My Question is on how to Serialize Client Side Entity Change Set with JSON.NET or any other approach with the entity state for each object.
For example if using BreezeJS (www.breezejs.com) all the changes made to the objects in the client application are sent in one bundle to the web api SaveChanges method where they are applied to the underlying database(Inserted,Updated,Deleted etc). 
 How can a .NET ( windows ,WPF,XAML) application work the same way as Breezejs entity manager works with webapi.
Any idea.
Thanks.

Comment: Check this.http://johnnycode.com/2012/04/10/serializing-circular-references-with-json-net-and-entity-framework/